# multiple views in a single RViz instance? RQT?

Tags: ros, rviz, visualization, rqt-gui, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm afraid I already know the answer, but does anyone know whether it is possible to configure RViz to give me 4 views in a single instance, similar to the *Quad View* in Blender:

http://wiki.blender.org/uploads/6/6a/3D_Interaction-Navigating-3D_view-Quad_View.png

I've been playing around with an `rqt_gui` instance and adding 4 RViz plugin instances, but somehow that seems a bit involved for what I'm trying to achieve, and I cannot get rid of the menu and status bars, leading to large gaps between the viewports in the RViz instances. I'm not too sure about the resource usage of such a configuration either.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197143/multiple-views-in-a-single-rviz-instance?-rqt?/) by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86574 on 2014-11-10

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rviz cannot do this directly, but it is supported by the underlying rendering engine (Ogre), so it should be possible to write an rviz plugin which shows additional views.

If you're interested in writing such a plugin, you may be able to use the rviz oculus rift plugin as an inspiration.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-11-12**:
Hm, you're right. I sort of expected an answer like this. Perhaps a candidate for the 'rainy day' list :).

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-03-11**:
It looks like this is still the correct answer :(
But another example has been posted since then: https://answers.ros.org/question/215975/multiple-display-with-rviz/